# Spring Integration - upload file to Dynamic SFTP Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-sftp

I am trying to upload files to dynamic SFTP servers whose config details I will receive in a String message with file content.
I have researched about spring Integration which will help me in dynamically connecting to SFTP servers to upload the data.I have tried to use generic Message for the current use case.

```
StandardIntegrationFlow flow =
        IntegrationFlow.from(()-> new GenericMessage<>(content,
                Map.of("file_name", "test.txt", "path", "/home)),
                e -> e.poller(poller))
            .handle(handler).get();
```

But I have to mandatorialy provide poller for that even if it is string data which is not correct.
Also one concern is there could be many Integration Flows that I might start dynamically so how will those be handled.
Is there any other cleaner way by which I can accomplish this?

Edit:
I am receiving a PubSub message which is having config details for SFTP server where I need to upload and the file details as well.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic SFTP server choice you might need to look into a `DelegatingSessionFactory`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-dsf.

So, you have to supply all the possible connection factories and have them to be chosen by the key you may provide in a message.

Your code snippet is not clear. That `IntegrationFlow.from(()->` is a source polling channel adapter which indeed requires a poller to initiate the flow.